# reading x86 jump within function

Tags: c, conditional-statements, assemblies

I am looking at the following assembly code generated by objdump -d:

```
    00000000004012a7 <phase_1>:
    4012a7:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
    4012ab:       be 68 24 40 00          mov    $0x402468,%esi
    4012b0:       e8 37 00 00 00          callq  4012ec <strings_not_equal>
    4012b5:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
    4012b7:       74 05                   je     4012be <phase_1+0x17>
    4012b9:       e8 f1 01 00 00          callq  4014af <phase_2>
    4012be:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
    4012c2:       c3                      retq
```

I need to make sure I know where the jump instruction is supposed to go to. Does it jump to add $0x8,%rsp (because the number in the left column matches the number to the right of je) or does it have something to do with the +0x17 at the end of the je line?

Comment: `<phase_1+0x17>` is `4012a7+17` which is `4012be`. Both numbers are the same.

Comment: It skips the `callq` instruction.

Comment: `objdump` is simply displaying the target address in two different ways, as a whole address and also as an offset from the function label.

Comment: The branch offset is from where the Program Counter (or Instruction Pointer) is *after* the branch instruction is processed. That offset is `05`. Notice that the `callq` instruction takes 5 bytes.